# PhoneGap Media Plugin - iOS - Play Sounds As Sound Effects

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using the latest PhoneGap (3.3.0) and the Media plugin - I'm not using it in a music app or anything - I just need to use my sounds for notifications (like when a new message is received). I'm using my iPad and the volume of alert sounds is always controlled by the hardware buttons on the side, which controls the Sound Effects volume, but the Media Plugin sounds are controlled by the media volume instead. It's a major problem because users with their vibrate switch on may get an unwelcome sound effect, while others will expect the sound effects to play according to the Sound Effects volume level and be surprised when they see a message they didn't hear come in. Is there a way, besides push notifications, for my app to receive sound effects that actually behave as sound effects?

I set `playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked` to `false` hoping that it would make the sound play as an actual Sound Effect, but apparently it just makes the sound obey the hardware mute switch.

```
  var snd = new Media("sounds/xylo.wav");
  snd.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false });
```

Thanks